# IDE for ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

My requirement is to create a web application in ASP 3.0. I downloaded Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013 and found that both offers support for 4.0 or above. Does anyone know where I can download an IDE for ASP.NET version 3.5?

[image]

Comment: Are you saying classic ASP 3.0? or ASP.NET? your topic title and question differ slightly, but importantly.

Comment: VS 2012 and 2013 both **also** support .NET 2.0, 3.0, 3.5

Answer (score 8):

There is no separate IDE for different version of .Net framework, You can change the Target Platform to .Net 3.5 in your project properties.

Right click on project and go to properties, there change Target framework. 
[image]

Comment: There is no option to create a new project in version 3.5. If I try to change the target to 3.5 after creating in 4.0, it is showing a lot of errors.

Comment: Check your other project target framework. You need to downgrade just in case.I am using version 3.5. If there is no option to create a new project. Create a project first in 4.0 then downgrade.